# Rails rake task to display version returning error of Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - VERSION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

So like many I am making use of the "isolation" to try to learn some new skills, in-particular rake tasks.

I am trying to build a rake task to version my rails app. I found a stackoverflow question with an answer that caught my eye and so I tried to run with it. However when I try to run the task, it gives me this error.

Error:

```
╰─ rake version:minor                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ─╯
rake aborted!
VERSION file not found or unreadable.
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/lib/tasks/version.rake:21:in `rescue in read_version'
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/lib/tasks/version.rake:17:in `read_version'
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/lib/tasks/version.rake:52:in `<main>'
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'  

Caused by:
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - VERSION
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/lib/tasks/version.rake:19:in `read'
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/lib/tasks/version.rake:19:in `read_version'
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/lib/tasks/version.rake:52:in `<main>'
/Users/taurengroup/Desktop/Roadze TMS/roadze-web/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

I know this is telling me i have a file path error, but I am not 100% sure on how to resolve this, and most of the answers I've found seem a bit muddy to me.

the file path I'm trying to write to is:

```
app/config/initializers/version.rb
```

from there I would like to be able to populate this somewhere in my app.

`config/initializers/version.rb` currently looks like so:

```
module RoadzeWeb
  class Application
    VERSION
  end
end
```

my version.rake file looks like so:

```
def valid?(version)
  pattern = /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\-(dev|beta|rc\d+))?$/
  raise "Tried to set invalid version: #{version}" unless version =~ pattern
end

def correct_version(version)
  ver, flag = version.split '-'
  v = ver.split '.'
  (0..2).each do |n|
    v[n] = v[n].to_i
  end
  [v.join('.'), flag].compact.join '-'
end

def read_version
  File.read 'VERSION'
rescue StandardError
  raise 'VERSION file not found or unreadable.'
end

def write_version(version)
  valid? version
  begin
    File.open 'VERSION', 'w' do |file|
      file.write correct_version(version)
    end
  rescue StandardError
    raise 'VERSION file not found or unwritable.'
  end
end

def reset(current, which)
  version, flag = current.split '-'
  v = version.split '.'
  which.each do |part|
    v[part] = 0
  end
  [v.join('.'), flag].compact.join '-'
end

def increment(current, which)
  version, flag = current.split '-'
  v = version.split '.'
  v[which] = v[which].to_i + 1
  [v.join('.'), flag].compact.join '-'
end

desc 'Prints the current application version'
version = read_version
task :version do
  puts <<~HELP
    Available commands are:
    -----------------------
    rake version:write[version]   # set custom version in the x.x.x-? format
    rake version:patch            # increment the patch x.x.x+1 (keeps any flags on)
    rake version:minor            # increment minor and reset patch x.x+1.0 (keeps any flags on)
    rake version:major            # increment major and reset others x+1.0.0 (keeps any flags on)
    rake version:dev              # set the dev flag on x.x.x-dev
    rake version:beta             # set the beta flag on x.x.x-beta
    rake version:rc               # set or increment the rc flag x.x.x-rcX
    rake version:release          # removes any flags from the current version

  HELP
  puts "Current version is: #{version.green}"
end

namespace :version do
  desc 'Write version explicitly by specifying version number as a parameter'
  task :write, [:version] do |_task, args|
    write_version args[:version].strip
    puts "Version explicitly written: #{read_version.green}"
  end

  desc 'Increments the patch version'
  task :patch do
    new_version = increment read_version, 2
    write_version new_version
    puts "Application patched: #{new_version.green}"
  end

  desc 'Increments the minor version and resets the patch'
  task :minor do
    incremented = increment read_version, 1
    new_version = reset incremented, [2]
    write_version new_version
    puts "New version released: #{new_version.green}"
  end

  desc 'Increments the major version and resets both minor and patch'
  task :major do
    incremented = increment read_version, 0
    new_version = reset incremented, [1, 2]
    write_version new_version
    puts "Major application version change: #{new_version.green}. Congratulations!"
  end

  desc 'Sets the development flag on'
  task :dev do
    version, flag = read_version.split '-'
    new_version = [version, 'dev'].join '-'
    write_version new_version
    puts "Version in development: #{new_version.green}"
  end

  desc 'Sets the beta flag on'
  task :beta do
    version, flag = read_version.split '-'
    new_version = [version, 'beta'].join '-'
    write_version new_version
    puts "Version in beta: #{new_version.green}"
  end

  desc 'Sets or increments the rc flag'
  task :rc do
    version, flag = read_version.split '-'
    rc = /^rc(\d+)$/.match flag
    new_version = if rc
                    [version, "rc#{rc[1].to_i + 1}"].join '-'
                  else
                    [version, 'rc1'].join '-'
                  end
    write_version new_version
    puts "New version release candidate: #{new_version.green}"
  end

  desc 'Removes any version flags'
  task :release do
    version, flag = read_version.split '-'
    write_version version
    puts "Released stable version: #{version.green}"
  end
end
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!